# UP/DOWN Run test: How to determine the Matrix $A$

Tags: references, simulation, runs

A test statistic for a UP/DOWN run is defined in ***Donald E. Knuth, The
Art of Computer Programming Volume 2, 1998, pp. 66-.***:

$V= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i,j\ <=m} \  (COUNT(i)-nb_i)(COUNT(j)-b_j)a_{ij}$

where $m$ is the max length of the runs.
But he doesn't describe how matrix $A$ and vector $B$ is defined. How are they defined in an UO/DOWN runtest?

Comment: In general I have difficulty finding  relevant information and examples regarding UP/DOWN tests. Feel free to suggest some links etc